# Which API should I use to query about 5k, 10k, or 15k records per call?

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api, bulk-api

Which API should I use to query report(50 columns) about 5k, 10k, or 15k records per call? Can I use the Rest API for this? Or it should be Bulk API or SOAP API?

Comment: Pagination occurs automatically, and I'm pretty sure you can't do more than 2k records per call no matter what you do.

Comment: @sfdcfox 
        Batches for data loads can consist of a single CSV, XML, or JSON file that is no larger than 10 MB.
        **A batch can contain a maximum of 10,000 records.** [->proof<-](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_concepts_limits.htm)
        A batch can contain a maximum of 10,000,000 characters for all the data in a batch.
        A field can contain a maximum of 32,000 characters.
        A record can contain a maximum of 5,000 fields.
        A record can contain a maximum of 400,000 characters for all its fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is to make a batch class for this. I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do with the data though so this may not be the best answer.

a batch class will allow you to query your entire database and perform functionality on whatever you please with no limitations (Besides time)

Comment: I want to integrate SF with my web service, which generate csv files based on diffrent criteries . For this I need report or some objects from SF.  But  Objects have got over 20k records, at this time report(based on objects and created in SF) consist less than 5k records. I can use Salesforce API, but can't  change or write Apex code in Salesforce. This mean, that I can't to use batch classes.